# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer doesn't inject values

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I've already spent several hours googling but still can do nothing.

Using debugger, I can find out that user and password in my datasource are not replaced with values from properties file, but parsed as is like `${jdbc.user}` and `${jdbc.password}` respectively.

What am I doing wrong?

This is jdbc.properties file (located at src/main/resources):

```
jdbc.username=user
jdbc.password=password
```

And here's spring configuration xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>jdbc.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

...

And that's dependency from pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: check in you war file if the file is being copies succesfuly.

Comment: Are you resolving the values in the same application context? You will need a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for each individual context (if needed).

Comment: AmitChotaliya, the application is not a web one and doesn't run in container.

Comment: I guess it could be like this `jdbc.username="user"` instead without quotes

Comment: How are you running the application?

Comment: XmlBeanFactory parent =
                new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("Parent.xml", SomeClass.class));
        final XmlBeanFactory springBeanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".xml", getClass()), parent);

Comment: Are you launching it with gradle, maven, direct from the command line?

Comment: Bart, I'm not very confident with Spring yet, but that's all in one config file, so it should be within one context, am I right?

Comment: Dave Morrissey, no, I compile project with maven and then run it with IDE.

Comment: Then I'm guessing your IDE isn't configured to include src/main/resources in the build classpath. Maven will find resources there by default but the IDE won't, unless you're using a maven plugin in the IDE.

Comment: IDE is configured to see resources and it finds spring configuration xml which is in resources directory too and I use maven plugin BTW.

Comment: If they aren't replaced you aren't using an `ApplicationContext`. My guess is that you are using a `BeanFactory` to load your xml file. Which basically doesn't do anything with the placeholders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way you launch your application.

```
XmlBeanFactory parent = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("Parent.xml",SomeClass.class)); 
final XmlBeanFactory springBeanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".xml", getClass()), parent);
```

Don't use a `BeanFactory` use an `ApplicationContext`.

```
String context = getClass().getSimpleName() + ".xml";
ApplicationContext parent = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Parent.xml");
ApplicationContext child = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {context}, parent);
```

A `BeanFactory` is just a factory for beans, nothing more nothing less. The `ApplicationContext` is a `BeanFactory` on steroids. It has a complete lifecycle and has special types of beans that are called during that lifeccycle.

Check [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory) of the reference guide.

Another tip, use the namespace to configure the placeholder support instead of the bean declaration and it is always wise to prefix it with from where/how you want it to be loaded.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/jdbc.properties" />
```

A final word on the placeholder support. This class is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and it will process bean definitions and replace the placeholders in them. However it does this only for beans in the same application context!. If you defined this bean in the parent and expect it to replace placeholders in the child context then that isn't going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Spring to search the classpath for the properties file, otherwise it will not be able to find it. Change the property file location from `jdbc.properties` to `classpath:/jdbc.properties`.

Comment: Unfortunetely, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this resolver instead:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```